# Angular For Loop Error. whenever I am trying to iterate on an array its show some error

Tags: angular

I am getting this error-> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.

I have an array named collection. initially set to {} and after a clicking on a button its value became initialized.

please refer below:-
..........

list-resturant.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of collection">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.address}}</td>
            <td>{{item.type}}</td>

</tr>
```

(list-resturant.component.ts)

```
export class ListResturantComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private restobj:ResturantService) { }
  collection={};
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.restobj.getList().subscribe((result)=>{
      console.warn(result);
      this.collection=result; //here 
    });
  }
```

Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Initialize it to empty array `[]`  instead of empty object.

Comment: your collection is an object... we cannot iterate an object... what is the data you're getting as result of your API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array to `*ngFor`, so instead of initializing `collection` to empty object `{}`, you can simply initialize to an empty array `[]`:

```js
collection = [];
```

However, since you are setting the collection from the result of an observable, you can simply use the observable directly in the template by using the `async` pipe (instead of subscribing in the controller):

```js
export class ListResturantComponent {

  collection$ = this.restobj.getList();

  constructor(private restobj:ResturantService) { }

}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of collection$ | async">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.address}}</td>
    <td>{{item.type}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Actually I have find out solution myself. I am using collection=Object() instead of collection={} and its work fine

Comment: Thanks for find out solution @BizzyBob